Is there any operator to calculate percentage (with % sign format) in Python dataframe?
I have two columns in my dataframe, and I want to calculate the percentage using these two columns (column A values < column B values). Is there any way to create a third column as a percentage column in this dataframe?
I tried dividing the columns which gives the answer in decimal points, but I need the answer with the sign of % with desired decimal places.

A percentage is just a value relative to 100. In order to display it as a percentage (e.g 27.3%) you will need to format it as a string. See Fancier Output Formatting, for the methods you can use.

I found the answer! This worked for me.
If I have two columns A and B in a dataframe df, assuming A < B, then I can create a column C as, A divided by B. Then apply lambda function on C for the % format.
I used 0.2 to get 2 decimal points, it can be changed for different decimal point.
df['C']=df['A']/df['B']    
df['C']=df['C'].apply(lambda x:f"{x:0.2%}")


If you want the percenatge sign in the dataframe when you created it, you can do something like this.
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Value1': [1, 2, 3] , 'Value2': [4, 5, 6]})
df.insert(2,'Percent', [f"{i:.2%}" for i in df['Value1']/df['Value2']])   
print(df)

The result is:
Value1  Value2 Percent
0       1       4  25.00%
1       2       5  40.00%
2       3       6  50.00%

